# Flash print to photo paper?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a image that I create using PHP and I want my end user to be able to print it off on photo paper.

How can I do this using flash? I looked at the print job class and was unsure of where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good place to start http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/206/1/The-PrintJob-class/Page1.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do using the ActionScript 3.0. Please check PrintJob Class for your task to be get completed.